# Hiding/Showing Specifics Divs Based on Web Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, show-hide

I have two videos. I need one video to be seen in Chrome/Safari/IE/Opera only. And I need the other video to be seen in Firefox only.

How would I go about doing this?

HTML:

*Video I need to be seen in Chrome/Safari/IE/Opera:

```
<div id="video1">
<video src="work_1.mov" width="500" height="288" preload="" controls>
</video>
</div>
```

*Video I need to be seen in Firefox:

```
<div id="video2" >
<video width="500" height="288" preload="" controls>
<source src="videos/work2.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="videos/work2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? BTW I will recommend to do this by checking features in browser instead of user agent. There are many things to do this. For example http://modernizr.com/ library

Comment: Why do you need to separate by browser may I ask?

Comment: Because Firefox will not accept the same video embed code as other browsers, and I don't want two videos to be featured on the same page @DSG.

Comment: might consider a javascript plugin that takes care of detection transparently and sets proper source. You just st up the config for sources, sizes etc and let it run i all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go with browser detection, versus, say, object detection, you can use jQuery.browser to flag the usual suspects: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Feature detection is the better route though, and using jQuery for this only makes sense if you need to test for the user agent specifically. *Note that jQuery recommends using Modernizr for going the feature detection route: http://modernizr.com/

If you insist on checking for browser type:

```
alert($.browser);
alert($.browser.version);
```

Comment: `$.browser` isn't in jQuery core anymore. This is not a good suggestion compared to feature detection. Very old school

Comment: Totally agreed. Feature detection is the way to go, and for that jQuery itself recommends Moderdizr.